# Can't run C program: "a.out: command not found"

Tags: terminal, sh

I have written my first program in C. I compiled it and it put a file on the desktop called `a.out`(as the book i am reading told me it should), but when i type the command `a.out` into terminal and run it it says `-bash: a.out: command not found`. Why is it saying this?

According to the book "Programming in C" by Stephen Kochan, what i am doing is correct because i am in the right directory(desktop), i believe. It also says that if the file is not in the correct path i can either add it to the path or run `./a.out`, this method works and runs the program, why is this?

Comment: This isn't so much a `c` problem, as a `not knowing how bash works` problem. Look into that instead.

Comment: That directory is not the "desktop". It's your current working directory, probably your home directory if you haven't run a `cd` or `pushd` command.

Comment: It says `a.out` is not found because it is not in your PATH. Just type `./a.out` as you already discovered works. And read the advice of @AntonH

Answer (score 39):

When you type a command name in bash (`a.out` is no different from any other command name in this respect), the shell searches for an executable file with that name. It performs this search using a list of directory names stored in your `$PATH` environment variable.

You can see your current `$PATH` by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

at your shell prompt. A typical value might be something like

```
/usr/bin:/bin
```

though you'll probably have some additional directories as well.

Since `a.out` is in your *current working directory* (type `pwd` to see what directory that is), and your current working directory probably isn't in your `$PATH`, you can't execute it by typing just `a.out`.

Since you can refer to your current directory as `.`, you can (and should) execute the command by typing

```
./a.out
```

NOTE: You *can* have `.` in your `$PATH`, but it's considered a bad idea to do so, since it makes it too easy to execute random commands accidentally. If `.` is at the front of your `$PATH`, imagine that I ask you to `cd` to my directory and type `ls` -- but I've installed a file called `ls` that does something nasty. Putting `.` at the *end* of your `$PATH` alleviates that risk, but it doesn't eliminate it entirely. It's best to cultivate the habit of referring to an executable file named `foo` as `./foo` if you want to execute it from the current directory.

(I've ignored the fact that aliases, functions, and shell built-in commands can also be executed this way.)

Comment: slashes aren't allowed in filenames. And i think you tried to say some other thing in the NOTE paragraph.

Comment: @Vicrobot: I don't understand your comment. Slashes (and null characters) aren't allowed in file names, but they're certainly allowed in file paths. What I'm suggesting in the NOTE is that if you have an executable called `a.out` in the current directory, it's best to execute it by typing `./a.out` rather than by adding `.` to your `$PATH`. Was that unclear in my answer?

Comment: Sorry; i thought that you're asking for filename to start with `./`   ; my fault. Well got the answer!!

Comment: @Vicrobot I can see how you got that impression. I've updated my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to type `./a.out`. That `./` tells the bash to look for file `a.out` in the current directory (dot - `.` - is pointing to the current directory).

If you type `a.out` in bash, without specifying the directory, it will search for it through directories in `$PATH` variable (if you're interested to see these, run `echo $PATH`). So you can either tell it to run the file present in the current directory, or you can add current directory (or Desktop directory) to the `$PATH`.

Comment: This makes sense, but if i am in the desktop and the file is on the desktop shouldnt `a.out` work?

Comment: No, it should not. If you type `a.out`, bash is looking for it in directories stored in `$PATH` env. variable. Desktop is usually not in `$PATH`.

Comment: @Justin: Not on Unix, as current directory is normally not in the search path. Putting it there is a security risk.

Comment: @Justin: DOS/cmd does that; many standard *nix setups don't. It's easy to add . to the PATH (`PATH="$PATH:."`). Btw having the current directory in the front, not the end of PATH can be considered a security risk because somebody could put a script in a directory which is named `ls` but deletes all jpegs in your home directory.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Even putting it in the back is considered a security risk, because there are typos.

Comment: @Deduplicator ah well. since yesterday that is my least worry. I never mispel anything.